# Rackspace: Temporary streaming URL to a file in the cloud files

Tags: cloud, url, rackspace, streaming

The question is simple: How to create a temporary **streaming** URL to a files in the *Rackspace cloud files*. URL is needed **streaming**.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a read of the [FAQ about streaming](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/getting-started-with-cloud-files-streaming).  Seems fairly self explanatory.

Did you try googling? I searched "rackspace cloud files streaming"